# Google SignIn is getting Exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, google-signin

I am working on `Google SignIn`. After Pressing the SignIn Button i got the exception. I am taking `GoogleService-Info.plist` also

> The Exception is: Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Your app is missing support for
>   the following URL schemes:
>   com.googleusercontent.apps.337335047637-ciu1dmqo156sdv1idjmm9olljduofdam'

Comment: Are you adding a URL scheme into project.

Comment: How can i add  URL scheme

Comment: Also check are you add a client id into your Google-Info.plist.

Comment: Yes, I downloaded and added to my project, Are we have to made any changes in info.plist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Sign-in requires a custom URL Scheme to be added to your project. To add the custom scheme:

1. Open your project configuration: double-click the project name in the left tree view. Select your app from the TARGETS section, then select the Info tab, and expand the URL Types section.
2. Click the + button, and add a URL scheme for your reversed client ID. To find this value, open the GoogleService-Info.plist configuration file, and look for the REVERSED_CLIENT_ID key. Copy the value of that key, and paste it into the URL Schemes box on the configuration page. Leave the other fields blank.

For more details check here.

Add a URL scheme to your project

[Google Sign in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating)

Answer (score 0):

This error comes because you didn't set URLScheme correctly for Google Sign-In.

From iOS9, it's mandatory to whitelist all the URLSchemes before using. Otherwise `canOpenURl` throw errors.

To Solve the above issue, you need to whitelist your URLScheme in *GoogleInfo.plist*

Paste the below code into the .plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>com.example.foo</string>
    <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.337335047637-ciu1dmqo156sdv1idjmm9olljduofdam</string>
    <string>com-google-gidconsent-google</string>
    <string>com-google-gidconsent-youtube</string>
    <string>com-google-gidconsent</string>
    <string>com.google.gppconsent.2.4.1</string>
    <string>com.google.gppconsent.2.4.0</string>
    <string>googlechrome</string>
    <string>googlechrome-x-callback</string>
</array>
```